# Program not working for IAR EW for msp430

Tags: msp430, iar

the #include isnt blue like it is in my lab manual for my class. I dont know if this is the issue or not. I have just installed the software according to the dirrections and restarted 3 times and I havent found any answers online
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Ak7.png)

Comment: The labels must start in the first column, otherwise the assembler will interpret them as instructions

Answer (score 0):

The format of an Assembly source line for the IAR Assembler is as follows:

```
[label [:]] [operation] [operands] [; comment ]
```

where the components are as follows:

- **label**: A definition of a label, which is a symbol that represents an address. If the label starts in the first column - that is, at the far left on the line. The `:` (colon) is optional.
- **operation**: An assembler instruction or directive. This must not start in the first column - there must be at least one   (whitespace) or a `→` (TAB) character prior it.
- **operands**: An assembler instruction or directive can have from zero up to several operands. The operands are separated by `,` (commas) or   (whitespaces).
- **comment**: Comment, preceded by a `;` (semicolon) -or- by a C/C++ comment styles (`/* ... */` or `//`).